# how to make an installed package as a service in ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, openconnect

I've installed the `ocserv` package using these commands on Ubuntu 22:

```
mkdir /usr/local/src/ocserv 
cd /usr/local/src/ocserv 
wget ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/ocserv/ocserv-0.10.9.tar.xz 
unxz ocserv-0.10.9.tar.xz 
tar xvf ocserv-0.10.9.tar 
cd ocserv-0.10.9 
./configure --sysconfdir=/etc/ && make && make install
```

The `ocserv` package is installed and it run and works with this command:

```
ocserv -c /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf
```

I need it to run as a service though. Can you please help me doing this?

I couldn't use the Linux repository to install this package because of some considerations.

Comment: What do you mean that you want to run it as a service? Do you want systemd to automatically run it on boot?

Comment: https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/ is a very good start

Comment: Misuse of the term "package" and a misleading title. That process does not install the "ocserv package". That process compiles un-packaged ocserv software from source code. Big difference.

Comment: The source package appears to provide example .service files for both standalone and socket-activated systemd services, under `ocserv-0.10.9/doc/systemd/`